# Show there is $C < \infty$ such that $|f'(z)| \leq C \int_{\mathbb{D}} |f(x + iy)|$ for $|z|\leq 1/2$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, cauchy-integral-formula

The following is exercise 4.9 in Donald Marshalls Complex analysis.

Show that there is a constant $C < \infty$ so that if $f$ is analytic on $\mathbb{D}$, then

$$|f'(z)| \leq C \int_{\mathbb{D}} |f(x+iy)| dxdy$$

for $|z| \leq 1/2$.

Here is my try: Let $A$ be the closed region bounded between the circles centered at $0$ of radius $3/4$ and $9/10$. It suffices to show that that there is $C < \infty$ such that

$$|f'(z)| \leq C\int_{A} |f(x+iy)| dxdy$$

Indeed, let $|z| \leq 1/2$ and $3/4 \leq r \leq 9/10$. Define $D_r$ to be the disk centered at the origin of radius $r$. Then, by the Cauchy Integral Formula

\begin{align}
|f'(z)| & = \left| \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial D_r} \frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta - z)^2} d\zeta \right| \\
& = \left|\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{f(re^{i\theta})}{|re^{i\theta} - z|^2} rie^{i\theta} d\theta \right| \\
& \leq \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{|f(re^{i\theta})|}{|re^{i\theta} - z|^2} rd\theta \\
& \leq \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{|f(re^{i\theta})|}{(r-1/2)^2} r d\theta \\
& \leq \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{|f(re^{i\theta})|}{(1/4)^2} r d\theta \\
& \leq \frac{8}{\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} |f(re^{i\theta})| r d\theta 
\end{align}

Define $C = 8/\pi\cdot\frac{1}{9/10 - 3/4}$. Note $\int_A |f(x+iy)| < \infty$ and so by Fubini's Theorem and a change of variables

\begin{align}
8/\pi\cdot\frac{1}{9/10 - 3/4} \int_A |f(x+iy)| dxdy & = \frac{1}{9/10 - 3/4} \int_{3/4}^{9/10} 8/\pi \int_0^{2\pi} |f(re^{i\theta})|r  d\theta dr \\
& \geq \frac{1}{9/10 - 3/4} \int_{3/4}^{9/10} |f'(z)| dr \\
& = |f'(z)|
\end{align}

Does this solution seem correct? Any comments or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't want = there.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Take a look at your first equality. Also what happened to $C?$

Comment: Ah, I forgot to put in the $1/2\pi i$. It is fixed now.

Comment: Your second paragraph!!

Comment: What is wrong with the second paragraph? I am substituting $C = 8/\pi$ and use the inequality from the first paragraph.